# JS not working. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```js
window.store = {
        localStoreSupport: function() {
            try {
                return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        set: function(name,value,days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }
            else {
                var expires = "";
            }
            if( this.localStoreSupport() ) {
                localStorage.setItem(name, value);
            }
            else {
                document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
            }
        },
        get: function(name) {
            if( this.localStoreSupport() ) {
                var ret = localStorage.getItem(name);
                //console.log(typeof ret);
                switch (ret) {
                  case 'true': 
                      return true;
                  case 'false':
                      return false;
                  default:
                      return ret;
                }
            }
            else {
                var nameEQ = name + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                    var c = ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
                        ret = c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
                        switch (ret) {
                          case 'true': 
                              return true;
                          case 'false':
                              return false;
                          default:
                              return ret;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        },
        del: function(name) {
            if( this.localStoreSupport() ) {
                localStorage.removeItem(name);
            }
            else {
                this.set(name,"",-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="a" placeholder="Var Name" /><br>
    <input id="b" placeholder="Var Value" /><br>
    <button onclick="n()">Save this var</button><br>
    <br><br>
    <input id="s" placeholder="Var to show" /><br>
    <button onclick="m()">Get the var's</button>
    <br><br>
    <input id="v" placeholder="var's to delete" /><br>
    <button onclick="del()">Delete var's</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Why isn't it working? It isn't saving the inputs, it keeps returning "null".
Could anyone give me a tip on what i did wrong here? I can't figure it out. It worked before, i did some minor changes but i don't know what i did anymore. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please write a better question, what are you trying to accomplish? What is expected and what is the results. Also what have you tried...

Comment: Please edit the title and the question your title is the worst kind there is. Read here  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, also where are the functions n(), & m() ?

Comment: do you have external js file?

Comment: Down here fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i found out after some testing is that in *get: function(name)* in the *if( this.localStoreSupport() )* block the variable *ret* should be like this:

```
var ret = localStorage.getItem(name.value);
```

and then everything should work like its supposed to.

[Click-> jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dk1fft9u/)

Comment: Thank you! This solved the issue. Stupid that this slwed me down this hard. Thanks a lot!